# Interpolate or "tween" between two values (but not animating)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable that is increasing let's say from 0 to 99.

Then I have a div that I want to move at the same rate of the increasing variable but I only want to define the two ends of the movement (for example moving from top to down, I only define the topmost position and the downmost position). The rest should be interpolated automatically while the main variable is changing it's value from 0 to 99.

All the search results I got were related to animating. But this is not exactly animating since the div should not move if the variable is not changing. How would you do this best in javascript?

EDIT: Some mock up code (probably has syntax errors ):

```
<html>

<body>

<div id="increase"></div>
<div id="move"></div>

</body>

</html> 

 <script>
var counter =0;
var topValue =50;
var bottomValue =150;
var interpolatedValue


$('#increase').click(){
counter++; 
}

$('#move').css(){
top: interpolatedValue; //this should be an interpolation between 50 and 150 based on the current counter value
}


</script>
```

Comment: Please provide some code that isn't doing what you want it to do. It is very difficult from your description to understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Is this for a progress indicator? You probably want to set the specific style value where you are increasing the value.

Comment: When you use the word "rate" of the changing variable, it makes it sound like animation, but based on other things you say, it sounds like the position is plain old based on the value or the variable. Is that correct?

Comment: You say that the value is increasing from 0 to 99. And then you say that this isn't animation because the value isn't changing. These are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Jon Hanna What I ment by saying that it's not an animation is that it's not time based. Meaning that I can't say "move for 2 seconds" or something like that. Because when the variable is not changing, the div is not moving either.

Comment: You don't need to say "move for 2 seconds". If you say "move", and then say "move" it'll animate.

Comment: @Jon Hanna Okay but with your definition every changing parameter is an animation. What if the variable changes once today and once after 3 days resulting in one shift of position for the div. Would you still refer to the behavior as an animation? Do you also call dynamically changing any css property with the term "animation"?

Comment: Yes. (Well, every changing *visible* parameter is an animation). Indeed, that's how javascript-based animation works. Though it doesn't look very animated if it doesn't change fast enough for the phi effect, it's still an animation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the top and bottom were 400 and 600 for instance, you can calculate the position based on the variable with some simple math.

```
var theVariable = 25; // 1 to 100
var top = 400;
var bottom = 600;
var distance = bottom - top;
var position = top + ((theVariable / 100) * distance); // 450
```

Comment: Yes, I think you got it. It was more simple than I thought!

Answer (score 13):

Something like:

```
// b - beginning position
// e - ending position
// i - your current value (0-99)
function getTween(b, e, i) {
    return b + ((i/99) * (e-b));
}
```

If your incrementing value is ever going to be different than 0-99, the hardcoded `99` in the function will need to be changed to something else, or pass in the max value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyVar = 0, Max = 99;
setInterval(increaseMyVar,30)//Call increaseMyVar every 30ms

function increaseMyVar()//MyVar Will go from 0 - 99
{
    MyVar = ++MyVar % Max;
}

//Do whatever you want with MyVar
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i would do it probably, that way you can "animate" multiple objects at once without changing much inside the script:

http://jsfiddle.net/pvKYX/

HTML:

```
<div class="mover" data-start="0" data-end="400" data-prop="margin-left"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
var p = 0;
function start(){
    $('.mover').each(function(){
        var $t = $(this);
       $t.css($t.data('prop'),$t.data('start')+($t.data('end')-$t.data('start'))/100*p);
    });
    if(p<100){
        p++;
        setTimeout(start,Math.round(Math.random()*500));
    }
}
start();
```

​

Comment: Great, this looks like what I need! Only the setTimeout is confusing me a bit, what does that part do?

Comment: Sorry I tested this and the movement of the divs is not connected to the var p value. Nothing should move unless p is changed.

Comment: @Sonypackman that's why i incremented p in the setTimeout loop for demonstration. you probably only need the $('.mover').each() part. that's where the values get updated depending on p.