# AngularJS model value interpolation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, interpolation, angular-ngmodel

I'm looking to have a model value change gradually once I set it, 
For example:

When I set the value at `$scope.data.value = 0;` to `$scope.data.value = 100` or perhaps have a method call, I'd like to gradually change the value rather than set it.

I know this can be done pretty simply with $interval, my question however is what's the best way to perform this in an angular setting?

Would I use a directive on the HTML model?

Again, I know this is simple stuff and has almost been asked before, my question relates specifically to an angular-wide implementation that could be re-used throughout a web application.

[Interpolate or "tween" between two values (but not animating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849654/interpolate-or-tween-between-two-values-but-not-animating)

I have a directive currently watching the model for change, as such, I don't really need the model to react in a specific way, I just need it to gradually update.

Maybe a service?

```
$valueInterpolator($scope.data.value, [value], [duration]);
```

Thanks for the input!

Comment: Why not use watchers?

Comment: @Thalaivar That would work, but I'd need to guarantee that the watcher is performed before any other watcher,